# Retrofit doesn't recognize nested json response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to get json response. I also generated model classes with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ However it doesn't work. The problem is json response doesn't fit to my java object. Am I miss something?

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "status_message":"Query was successful",
   "data":{
      "movie_count":1,
      "limit":20,
      "page_number":1,
      "movies":[
         {
            "id":4281,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/movie\/the-third-man-1949",
            "imdb_code":"tt0041959",
            "title":"The Third Man",
            "title_long":"The Third Man (1949)",
            "slug":"the-third-man-1949",
            "year":1949,
            "rating":8.3,
            "runtime":93,
            "genres":[
               "Film-Noir",
               "Mystery"
            ],
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"Not Rated",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/the_third_man_1949\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/the_third_man_1949\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/the_third_man_1949\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "date_uploaded":"2015-07-13 10:22:11",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1436739731
         },
      ]
   },
   "@meta":{
      "server_time":1436799207,
      "server_timezone":"Pacific\/Auckland",
      "api_version":2,
      "execution_time":"34.67 ms"
   }
}
```

Comment: "Am I miss something?" -- among possibly other things, your question is missing Java code. We cannot help you with your Java code if we cannot see your Java code. In other words, we need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Running your JSON through http://jsonlint.com/ there is a parse error on line 31. That may be your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem at line number 31 where you put a comma(,) after the 2nd bracket { . Remove the comma and everything is fine .

Comment: @krialix , Appreciate with Upvote if it is useful :).